# how do i prevent hotlinking of images in my wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, hotlinking

I have a wordpress website hosted on byethost.com which runs on a free account, now what the problem is that on some computers it shows that image hotlinking is disabled on my plan, is there a way to change my urls of images whithout giving my websites link, or i'll just have to upgrade my plan??

Answer (score 0):

You should add an entry to your .htaccess. [This page](http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/) has a handy generator that will write he rules for you.

As always with making changes to .htaccess, make sure you back it up first, and don't put it in between the comments added by WP, since they may get over written